# How can i split string having different delimeters in dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas

in my data set there are 4 columns and some of the rows have multiple entries separated by ";" in one column and "," in other how can i split them in separate rows

i tried using str.split of **pandas** and and stack method too but it only work for single delimeter i wnated to do it for entire dataframe having different delimeters

i tried using this but it also didn't work

```
[In]  df.set_index(['Year','Source title','Volume','Issue','Pagestart','Page end','Cited by','Abstract']).apply(lambda x :x.str.split(',')).stack().apply(pd.Series).stack()
```

i want to split data in a row into different rows here is an example 
my csv file :

```
Name     id    city 
a,b,c   1;2;3  x,y,z
d       4       w
```

wanted to convert into :

```
Name     id    city 
a        1       x
b        2       y
c        3       z
d        4       w
```

Comment: noop just a typo btw how can i solve this

Answer (score 1):

You can use multiple delimiters using `regex`:

```
df = df.apply(lambda x: x.str.split('[,;]').explode())

  Name id city
0    a  1    x
0    b  2    y
0    c  3    z
1    d  4    w
```

Comment: The '|' in brackets isn't an operator, and it is unnecessary.